# What is the best reinforcement learning algorithm for continuous action spaces?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, reinforcement-learning

Is there a general consensus on whether we should be using TRPO, PPO, ACER, A3C etc. or is it highly dependent on the situation?

It seems ACER and PPO are the current leaders but I'm not sure if this is entirely correct.

Comment: Could you please explain your abbrevs?